# Insertar datos en 2 o más tablas al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día todos, tengo el siguiente caso, estoy realizando una opción de eliminar, pero antes de ejecutar el delete, primero estoy haciendo un BackUp de la información. Replanteo el ejercicio de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT into Tabla destino 1 (valor1,valor2,valor3)
select valor1,valor2,valor3
from Tabla Origen 1 where id= id_extraido;

NSERT into Tabla destino 2 (valor1,valor2,valor3)
select valor1,valor2,valor3
from Tabla Origen 2 where id= id_extraido;
```

Los Valores provienen de distintas tablas de origen, el problema es que no sé como puedo realizar la transacción en una sola consulta query, es decir pasar los datos correspondientes a cada tabla en una sola query.

Cualquier ayuda o idea es bien recibida para mejorar mi aprendizaje.

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: Intente hacerlo así
INSERT into   Tabla destino 2
                         (valor1,valor2,valor3)
                        select  valor1,valor2,valor3
                        from    Tabla Origen 2
                        where   id= id_extraido;

INSERT into   Tabla destino 1
                         (valor1,valor2,valor3)
                        select  valor1,valor2,valor3
                        from    Tabla Origen 1
                        where   id= id_extraido;

Comment: @YordyMora agrega eso a tu pregunta, [editandolo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/444860/edit)

Comment: Vale vale, comprendo

Comment: ¿Cual sería el objetivo de ejecutar esas dos queries como una sola query?

Comment: Por lo que me han pedido y explicado, es mas limpio y corto el código durante su función, por ello pido ayuda por si alguien conoce alguna forma de su realización.

Comment: No entiendo con exactitud qué es lo que quieres lograr. Pero si se trata de simplificar puedes programar un TRIGGER del tipo [AFTER DELETE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-delete-trigger/) en las tablas para que la fila borrada se inserte en `TablaDestino...` Haciendo eso sólo tendrás que borrar y el TRIGGER hará el resto.

Comment: Vale, lo leeré, gracias por la idea.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que querés hacer es lo contrario de lo que explicas (pero por ahí me equivoco), ejectuar las dos queries dentro de una misma transacción.

Si querés mantener la consistencia de los datos, lo que deberías hacer es ejectuar ambas queries por separado, pero en una misma transacción (de esta manera garantizas de que si falla una de las queries se vuelva al estado que tenía la base de datos antes de comenzar la transacción).

Para ello deberías desahabilitar el autocommit, comenzar una transacción, ejecutar las queries y luego hacer un commit o rollback de la transacción dependiendo del resultado de la ejecución de las mismas. Esto depende de la librería que estés utilizando para conectarte a la base de datos.

Las transacciones siguen cuatro propiedades básicas: ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability):

- **Atomicidad**: aseguran que todas las operaciones dentro de la secuencia de trabajo se completen satisfactoriamente. Si no es así, la transacción se abandona en el punto del error y las operaciones previas retroceden a su estado inicial.
- **Consistencia**: aseguran que la base de datos cambie estados en una transacción exitosa.
- **Aislamiento**: permiten que las operaciones sean aisladas y transparentes unas de otras.
- **Durabilidad**: aseguran que el resultado o efecto de una transacción completada permanezca en caso de error del sistema.

[Documentación de php y MySQL Mejorado sobre como implementar las transacciones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.transactions.php).

También te recomiendo leer sobre [Prepared Statements o Sentencias Preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Oh okay, lo intentaré. 
Muchas Gracias

Comment: De nada @YordyMora! Espero te sirva de ayuda.